# After I save VBAProject.OTM and restart Outlook, macros can't work; the ribbon is greyed out

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm using a few VBA macros in Outlook 2013 Professional Plus in Windows 7 Family Version. After a windows crash, my macro in outlook can't work.

1. ALT+F11 open VBA editor, find all ribbons are grayed out, no project in Project window. can't edit VBA in editor.
2. close outlook, delete %userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Outlook\VBAProject.OTM, then restart outlook
3. ribbons are back to live, "Project1" show up in project window, i can insert new module and edit VBA and save macro.
4. after save, close outlook, confirm the new "VBAProject.OTM" is created with right time stamp.
5. restart outlook, back to 1, all ribbon grayed out, can't find macro/project, can't edit VBA.

I've checked with Google, but can't find similar issue or answers. 
tried delete office and reinstall, still not working.
Some article mentioned (Digital Certificate for VBA Projects and Visual Basic for Applications), both are installed.

appreciate if you could provide some input. 
thx a lot.

Some screen prints below:

*All ribbons grayed out, can't load or edit VBA*
[image: all robbins grey out, can't load or edit VBA]

*Delete VBAProject.OTM then restart outlook*
[image: delete VBAProject.OTM then restart outlook]

Comment: See if a Group Policy setting has to be changed by an adminstrator. Some info  http://windowsitpro.com/windows-server/access-denied-configuring-office-macro-security-multiple-users and https://www.slipstick.com/outlook/block-macros-office-20132016/

Comment: There are many posts on the net like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/45038449/1571407