# Outlook macros are disabled since Windows freezed previously

Tags: vba, outlook

We use VBA macros in our company on every computer where Outlook is installed. Macros are digitally signed with a certificate to ensure security. This certificate is generate through the **selfcert.exe** application. When we add the digital signature on the VBA project (which contains the macros) in Outlook we choose the certificate generated previously and we check that Outlook options in the '**Trust Center Settings**' are defined on '**Disable all macros except digitally signed macros**'. Next, the first time we launch Outlook and run a macro, we got a message to confirm with 3 buttons: 'Trust all documents from this publisher', 'Enable Macros', 'Disable Macros'. We always choose to trust all to avoid getting this message again next time. This is working pretty well since several years on every machine.

Some weeks ago, someone complains about **random freeze of Windows 10**. The IT support solved this issue but unfortunately a new problem appeared: Outlook macros are always disabled on this machine. I am pretty sure this new problem is due to the previous freeze of Windows. I also read someone somewhere which crashed the disk and then Outlook macros got disabled.

What I already tried:

- Remove/Add the certificate again
- Create a new certificate to sign my macros
- Renaming the VBA module containing the macros
- Deleting the VBA module and creating it again

None of these actions worked. Macros are still disabled.

The temporary solution for now is to change the Trust Center Settings options by enabling all macros. But I cannot accept this workaround which is potentially dangerous.

I already search hours on Google and tried suggestions without luck.

Comment: See if a Group Policy setting has to be changed by an adminstrator. Some info  http://windowsitpro.com/windows-server/access-denied-configuring-office-macro-security-multiple-users and https://www.slipstick.com/outlook/block-macros-office-20132016/

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your machine is corrupted. Try to repair Outlook or Office.

Be aware, you need to install a self-signed certificate as a trusted root CA in Windows. See [Installing a Self-Signed Certificate as a Trusted Root CA in Windows Vista](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/sbs/2008/05/08/installing-a-self-signed-certificate-as-a-trusted-root-ca-in-windows-vista/) for more information.

Also you may find the [Odd behaviour with macros being disabled](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/a786e82c-6eb5-453f-a3aa-b0739a81cad8/odd-behaviour-with-macros-being-disabled?forum=outlookdev) forum thread helpful. It states the following:

> I could reproduce the issue in Outlook 2013 (C2R 15.0.4927.1002). The macro would be disabled if I set 'Notifications for digitally signed macros, all other macros disabled' and i have added the CA into Trusted Publisher and Trusted Root CA list. The issue doesn't exist in Outlook 2016, I would suggest you use Outlook 2016 if you don't want to enable all macros. Besides, I suggest you submit your feedback on Outlook User Voice: https://outlook.uservoice.com/

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I'll first check which version of Outlook is installed on the user's computer. But I'm afraid this is already the 2016.